# vscode intellisense too slow working with PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Intellisense suggestions that pop-up while you write in visual studio code with python extension take toooo much time (like 20 seconds) to appear if you are using PyQt4 classes. I tried with different files, inside and outside a project, same results.
Even in a 40 lines .py that imports `from PyQt4 import QtGui`
and has a simple class that inherits from `QtGui.QTableWidget` suggestions take forever, and it's even worse if you hit ctrl+space, it wont load at all.

Commenting the import, and deleting the inheritance from PyQt4 classes, makes Intellisense work instantaneously again.

I wasn't sure if this justifies an issue in https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python

**maybe I'm doing something wrong?**

for completion, here are my user settings:

```
{
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=R,C",
        "--extension-pkg-whitelist=PyQt4"
    ],
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "csv-preview.separator": ";",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
        "--max-line-length=100"
    ]
}
```

update: Having the same project, Intellisense runs much faster in VS code under debian. (4-5 secs instead of 20+)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jedi is simply not fast when it comes to PyQt. It's a known issue and we are working on bringing the analysis engine from Visual Studio over to VS Code in the near future (following our blog at https://aka.ms/pythonblog for release announcements to know when it's available).